# can different calls to kernel share memory?

Tags: cuda

In my code, I need to call a CUDA kernel to parallelize some matrix computation. However, this computation must be done iteratively for ~60,000 times (kernel is called inside a 60,000 iteration for loop).

That means, If I do cudaMalloc/cudaMemcpy across every single call to the kernel, most of the time will be spent doing memory allocation and transfer and I get a significant slowdown.

Is there a way to say, allocate a piece of memory before the for loop, use that memory in each iteration of the kernel, and then after the for loop, copy that memory back from device to host?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do exactly what you describe:

```
int *h_data, *d_data;
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_data, DSIZE*sizeof(int));
h_data = (int *)malloc(DSIZE*sizeof(int));
// fill up h_data[] with data
cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, DSIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
for (int i = 0; i < 60000; i++)
  my_kernel<<<grid_dim, block_dim>>>(d_data)
cudaMemcpy(h_data, d_data, DSIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
...
```

Comment: Replacing `malloc()` with [cudaMallocHost()](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g9f93d9600f4504e0d637ceb43c91ebad.html#g9f93d9600f4504e0d637ceb43c91ebad) may improve performance.

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what I needed to do. But I wasn't sure, because I had to do other useful work inside the loop that use the results of the CUDA  computation.